# C program is not running on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[Image][1]I am using an Ubuntu machine. I want to run C program on Visual Studio code. I have installed C/C++ extension and CODE RUNNER extension to my VS Code. But when I am going to run a simple program, it is showing me errors. What should I do now ?

```
tony@Jarvis:~/Desktop/c program$ cd "/home/tony/Desktop/c program/" &&
gcc Hello World.c -o Hello World && "/home/tony/Desktop/c program/"Hello World

gcc: error: Hello: No such file or directory

gcc: error: World.c: No such file or directory

gcc: error: World: No such file or directory

gcc: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Try a filename without spaces in it.

Comment: Commonly, an IDE should be able to put quotation marks around paths and filenames to enable spaces. This is a VSC problem, not a GCC problem. GCC is happy to compile files with spaces in its name, **if it receives these quoted**.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should not contain any spaces. I see `Hello World.c`. This will not work. Try changing it to `HelloWorld.c`

Comment: I have tried this. I have saved this program like HelloWorld.c. But I am facing error.

Comment: cd "/home/tony/Desktop/c program/" . This folder name, 'c program' is also causing problems as it has a space in it. Try changing it to cprogram. The problem is quite simple. GCC cannot find you C file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name has spaces, `Hello World.c`. Having spaces while using a Command Line too like gcc is not good. Stay away from spaces as much as you can. In this case gcc thinks that `Hello` and `World.c` are separate files.

Comment: @Prince What's you new error? And it seems your directory has spaces in it. Another Problem.